# Sri Vishnu Gita is present in which Puranas or ancient texts or scriptures.?

Tags: scripture, shiva, vishnu, puranas, gita

I have came accross some questions in other public forums saying there is a vishnu gita claiming there lord vishnu gave his gita gyan to lord shiva. After searching a lot thankfully I came across this [sri Vishnu Gita](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook-shri-vishnu-gita) and the [audio book](https://archive.org/details/VishnuGitaAudioBook) of the same.  But in description it's saying that **"*Vishnu Gita is a dialogue between Lord Maha Vishnu and the Devatas...*"** and I have also found mentioning of a gita named "Vaishnava Gita" but couldn't find it.

So my three questions here.:

1. Is there any gita or texts where lord vishnu had gave gita gyan to lord shiva.?
2. Sri Vishnu Gita belongs to which purana or ancient texts.?
3. Details about "Vaishnava Gita".?

(Please while giving answer touch all three of these topics or atleast mention it as weather you know it or not, it will be very helpful and I will really appreciate it.)...

Comment: Q. So, this is a less known Vishnu Gita (Song) with no commentry by sny vaishnavas guru  or it doesn't existd only.???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > 1. Is there any gita or **texts** where lord vishnu had gave gita gyan to lord shiva.?

**Yes**, but not "gita gyan", but a sect based "gyan (knowledge)" of the Pancharatras. As discussed in [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18905/which-scriptures-state-vishnu-teaching-principles-of-vaishnavism-to-his-four-dis), there's a general belief system within the Vaishanava community, that Lord Vishnu have imparted the knowledge of the Pancharatra philosophy to "four of his disciples": Devi Lakshmi, Lord Brahmā, Sanatakumaras & **Lord Shiva**, and thus accounting for the fact that Shiva is considered as the foremost of the *Vaishanava.* This forms the crux of the Vaishavnava theology based [Rudra Sampardaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudra_Sampradaya#:%7E:text=In%20Hinduism%2C%20the%20Rudra%20Sampradaya,disciplic%20succession%20in%20the%20religion.&text=According%20to%20Vaishnavism%2C%20Shiva%2C%20who,Vaishnava%2C%20or%20follower%20of%20Vishnu.)

However, no supporting verses for the claims is found by the OP in that answer. Although, [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/where-in-padma-purana-the-following-verse-about-parampara-is-located) does produces some proof ratifying the beliefs held about the 'Paramparaa/lineage' based sects said to have been started by the "four disciples of Vishnu". The answer base its claims on some of extant manuscripts  based books, which might be based on some of the older lost verses of the Padma Purana.

---

> > 2. Sri Vishnu Gita belongs to which purana or ancient texts.?
>
> > 3. Details about "Vaishnava Gita".?

[This QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12466/how-many-types-of-gita-spoken-by-lord-krishnavishnu-himself) tries to discusses all the various known Gitas spoken by Lord Vishnu (or his incarnations). Further [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32134/where-exactly-is-ashtavakra-gita-found/41022#41022) tries to establish that, all the these "new" or alternative *gitas* are to be taken as the imitations of the "original" Srimad Bhagvad Gita by Lord Shri Krishna. How much to trust the veracity of these "imitation claims", is totally left to the reader's discretion.

The Gita you're asking is not specifically found anywhere, as named in the question - i.e., **no text as such is called or named as either the "Vishnu Gita" or "Vaishnava Gita"**. The content in the audio file, more likely seems to be part of the *Hamsa Gita*, which is a part of the final discourse given to Uddhava by Lord Krishna, found in the [Srimad Bhagavatam: Canto 11: Chapter 13](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/13/), before he retired from Earth, towards his transcendental form. In there, the Lord mentions a story of how once, the four *Sanat-Kumāras* engrossed with questions regarding the 'Goal of Yoga & Emancipation', approached Lord Brahmā. But, Lord Brahmā not able to answer the question, further meditated on the Lord, and the Lord thus appearing as the Hamsa (the incarnate Swan), resolved all the doubts of Lord Brahmā and the *Sanat-Kumāras*. The exact details maybe read in [this Answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18177/17833).

Another story of Hamsa (imparting on various *sadhyas*, the knowledge of emancipation and yoga) is mentioned in the Shanti Parva , Chapter 12 - [Mokshadharma Parva: Section CCC](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b127.htm), of the Mahabharata.

The translation, mentions the Swan, to be an incarnation of the non-personal Brahman (Supreme reality). Kindly note, this translation is from the SacredText website:

> "Bhishma said, 'In this connection I shall recite to thee an old
> narrative, O Yudhishthira, of the discourse between the Sadhyas and a
> Swan. **Once on a time the Unborn and eternal Lord of all creatures
> (viz., Brahman), assuming the form of a golden Swan, wandered through
> the three worlds till in course of his wanderings he came upon the
> Sadhyas.'**
>
> "The Sadhyas said, 'O ford, we are the deities called Sadhyas. We like
> to question thee. Indeed, we would ask thee about the religion of
> Emancipation. Thou art well-acquainted with it. We have heard, O bird,
> that thou art possessed of great learning, and eloquent and wise of
> speech. O bird, what dost thou think is the highest of all objects? O
> high-souled one, in what does thy mind find pleasure? Do thou,
> therefore, O foremost of birds, instruct us as to what that one act is
> which thou regardest as the foremost of all acts, and by doing which,
> O chief of the feathery creation, one may soon be freed from all
> bonds.'

However, in the same *Parva* , few sections before in the another sub - *parva*, [Rajadharmanusasana Parva: Section XLVIII](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a047.htm), *Bhishma* refers to Lord Krishna as the Golden Swan.

Although, as per [this source (on the Archive-Org Website/page 5216)](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/5216/mode/2up), for the same Mahabharata Parva, with Sanskrit-Hindi translation, the translator translates the word *Prajaapati* directly as Lord Brahma, rather than Vishnu or the impersonal Brahman. The translator has named the section itself as *Hamsa Gita* by Lord Brahmā.

> हंसोभूत्वाथ सौवर्णस्त्वजो नित्यः **प्रजापतिः** । 
> सवै पर्येति लोकांस्त्रीनथ साध्यानुपागमत् ॥ ३॥
>
> > एक समय नित्य अजन्मा **प्रजापति** सुवर्णमय हंसका रूप धारण करके तीनों लोकों में विचर रहे थे। घूमते-घामते वे साध्यगणोंके पास जा पहुँचे ॥३॥
> > Once upon a time the Unborn and eternal Lord of all creatures, i.e, the **Prajapati (viz., Lord Brahmā)**, assuming the form of a golden Swan, wandered through
> > the three worlds till in course of his wanderings he came upon the
> > Sadhyas

And thus, another case is made that this Gita is yet another Hamsa-Gita, albeit by Lord Brahmā to the Sādhyas, and not the one which Lord Vishnu is said to have imparted in the Srimad Bhagvatam.

**So basically, this so called "Vishnu Gita's" printed manuscripts (found on the Arhive-Org website) is nothing, but extracts and verses by various divinities taken from several scriptures, mainly including, from the *Hamsa Gita* itself, which is a part of the larger Uddhava Gita from Srimad Bhagvatam or, it is the Hamsa-Gita by Lord Brahmā (or Vishnu) (as a Golden Swan) from the Shanti-Mokshadharma Parva of the Mahabharata (subject to the translator's interpretation)**. Further, A lot of the audio also sounds purely similar to the Srimad Bhagavad Gita discourse too, which as discussed above is ratified by the "imitation claim".

Comment: Is Hamsa Gita imparted to Brahmaji same as the Hamsa Gita given to Sadhya devas?

Comment: @Archit. I have edited and added that doubt of yours. It seems that two interpretations seem to exist, Archive-Org based and SacredText based. Thus , the Mahabharata based Hamsa-Gita, can either be by Vishnu or BrahmA.

Comment: In any case, both Gitas will be different, Sadhya devas and the four Kumaras are different.

Comment: Okay cool. Basically someone created a Vishnu Gita from extracts of verses from two other Gitas? But there’s no Vishnu Gita. It’s an interpolated thing?

Comment: I'd be very surprised and maybe happy too, If someone could indeed find an actual proper reference for the presence of an "original" Vishu Gita (as asked by the OP),.. @Archit ,. In my view, it's an interpolation juxtaposed with several verses from various scriptures.

Comment: Haha anyways the answer deserved an upvote. Thanks.